# JSONs made from shapefiles are not plotting (using folium or Leaflet alone)

Tags: shapefile, leaflet, web-mapping, ogr2ogr, folium

My goal is to plot two shapefiles as layers on an interactive map.
The files I'm using live at https://github.com/AnnaMag/maps.

I transformed shapefiles to .geojson using

```
ogr2ogr -f ...
```

e.g. ogr2ogr -f geoJSON Wards2011.geojson Wards2011.shp

Neither of the files is being plotted using folium or Leaflet alone.

Code example for 1 shapefile:

```
#center in SA:
lllon = 15
lllat = -35
urlon = 33
urlat = -22

state_geo = r'data/Wards2011.geojson'
map = folium.Map(location=[(lllat+urlat)/2, (lllon+urlon)/2], zoom_start=6, 
tiles='cartodbpositron')
map.geo_json(geo_path=state_geo)


map.create_map(path='test.html')
```

Replacing the geo_path with:

```
state_geo = r'data/sal_population.json'
```

is not working either.

Is there anything wrong with the json files or the approach?

## UPDATE

As suggested I reduced the complexity:

1. in Wards shapefile I left only 4 necessary features (incl. geometry, of course)
2. Simplified the shapefiles

   ogr2ogr out.shp in.shp -simplify 0.000001
3. transformed to geojson

   ogr2ogr -t_srs EPSG:4326 -f GeoJSON Wards2011.geojson out.shp
4. transformed to topojson

   topojson --spherical  --properties -s 0.001 -q 1E6 -o Wards2011.topojson Wards2011.geojson

Neither of the files is working. What should be fixed to make it work?

Comment: is "Wards2011.json" the geojson output from ogr2ogr?

Comment: And is it working without the map.geo_json line?

Comment: yes, all *json are outputs from ogr2ogr. It does work without it.

Answer (score 2):

The geo_path you mentioned a path that is not valid! Your shapes are stored in the file *Wards2011.geojson* and not *Wards2011.json*

Furthermore your geojson has 143mb which is very much to handle. simplify the geometry of the shapefile! I have done something similar in QGIS and reduced 120mb to 4mb which works in a browser.

Comment: Apologies, it is a typo- I actually had 2 files: .json, and .geojson to try if it was extension problem (I did try everything I could think of). I changed it and tried again- the map is not even showing the background

Comment: Your files are definitely too big for a webmap!

Comment: thanks @Riccardo, makes sense. Can I plot it in QGIS or it's also too big?

Comment: it will plot in QGIS but I would prefer to work with the shapefile and simplify this. also remove columns that aren't needed.

Comment: I tried simplification with topojson and input the topojson file. Not working...

Comment: you checked this ressource @AnnaMagdalena? https://gist.github.com/wrobstory/5609811#file-antarctic_ice_edge-json

Comment: @Riccardo- I believe this is what I'm doing. The Python code will (upper gist) generate the index.html that is included as one of the gists (if ice_map.create_map(index.html) is added). I genuinely cannot see where my approach/code differs from the one in the link

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/36519/discussion-between-riccardo-and-anna-magdalena).